# Cycle2 Plugin Hide/Show buttons jQuery

Tags: controls, show-hide, jquery-cycle

I have used the jQuery cycle2 plugin on a blog website. What i want the slideshow to do is when there is more than 1 image displayed, the controls will show-at the moment they are hidden through css.

The plugin is used by declaring it in my header (here is the link to the js file:
http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js

And then my css contains a class for the container of the slideshow, class for the container for the buttons and a class each for prev and next buttons:

css:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    height:400px;
    z-index:0;
}

.cycle-slideshow  img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:3;
}

.center {
 display:none;  
}

.center a{
    z-index:4;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-48px;
}

.center a:hover {
    display:block;
}


.center a#prev, .center a#next{
    position:relative;
    width:4%;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;  
    color:#FFF;

}

.center a#next{
    float:right;
    background:url(images/next.png) center -2px no-repeat;
}

.center a#prev {
        float:left;
    background:url(images/prev.png) center -2px no-repeat;
}
```

My html code is actually embedded within a wordpress function but the html format goes along the lines of:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
    data-cycle-speed="200"
    data-cycle-next="#next"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev"
    data-cycle-swipe="true">

    //does stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="prev">&nbsp;</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="next">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
```

The following code i was told to do (the first three lines) but this still doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
            $('.cycle-slideshow').on( 'cycle-initialized', function( e, opts ) {
            if ( opts.slideCount > 1 ) {
                $(".center").css("display", "block");
            }
    });
});
```

Im not the best with jQuery so can anyone help or give me any guidance please?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are going to want to initialize the slideshow via code AFTER you add the event handler.  Remove the `cycle-slideshow`  class so it doesn't auto initialize and then you can do this:

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/zyhrK/1/

```
$('.slideshow').on('cycle-initialized', function (e, opts) {
    if (opts.slideCount > 1) {
        $(".center").css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    }
});

$('.slideshow').cycle();
```